# Logging function which uses operator <<

Tags: c++, operators

I'd like to write a function for logging which should be used like this:

```
log(__FILE__) << "My message containing integer: " << 123 << " and double: " << 1.2;
```

This should print the following line, add endl and flush immediately:

> main.cpp: My message containing integer: 123 and double: 1.2

My (simplified) attempt for the implementation of the function:

```
class Writer
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Writer & operator<<(T t)
    {
        cout << t << endl;
        cout.flush();
        return (*this);
    }
};

Writer log(const char* fileName)
{
    cout << fileName << ": ";
    return Writer();
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    log(__FILE__) << "My message containing integer: " << 123 << "and double: " << 1.2;
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that because of L-R associativity of the operator<< the output is:

> main.cpp: My message containing integer:
>
> 123
>
> and double:
>
> 1.2

Is there any way how to implement the function or is my requirement for its usage unrealizable?

Ideally I'd like to use plain C++03 (i.e. no C++11 features, boost and non-standard libraries).

Comment: Just to be clear: What needs to be flushed when and what should be on what line? For instance: Where did that "double ..." part go in your first example?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sorry, edited, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L-R associativity is not related to your problem (if you talk about line breaks). The problem is because you use endl after each write. You don't need it (and if you do that, then you don't need flush, because endl already flushes the output).

The easy solution to your problem:

```
class Writer
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Writer & operator<<(T t)
    {
        cout << t;
        return (*this);
    }

    ~Writer()
    {
        try {
            cout << endl;
        }
        catch (...) {
            // You have to make sure that no
            // exception leaves destructor
        }
    }
};
```

It is also worth to notice, that your approach is not really scalable: it is impossible to use your code in multi-threaded environment. Assume that two threads are writing into your logging:

```
Thread 1: log(__FILE__) << "a" << "b" << "c";
Thread 2: log(__FILE__) << "a" << "b" << "c";
```

Here you can easily get a message "aabbcc\n\n" in your logfile, which is highly undesirable.

In order to avoid that, you can have a static mutex object inside log() function, which you pass into Writer constructor. Then you have to lock it in the constructor and unlock it in the destructor. It will guarantee the synchronization of concurrent writing of different entries.

Comment: put a try-catch around that destructor code and I'll give you a +1

Comment: Why do you need a try/catch?

Comment: Technically, Richard is right: cout<<endl can throw an exception, but throwing exceptions from destructors is a completely wrong idea (you can find a lot about that in the Internet). So it is a must to make all of the destructors non-throwing. I didn't want to clutter the code, so I kept the example as short as possible, but now I think that it is good to pay special attention to this issue in my snipped, because not everyone is aware of importance of this. So I added the exception check.